# trying to install Ralink rt3092 wirless drivers HELP!

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ralink

using ubuntu 20.04 I'm trying to install some kind of drivers that will work for me I have the Ralink rt 3092 can someone please find me workaround or help ..my wifi cuts out every 20 mins I'm simply trying to fix the issue and maybe speed up the connection a little. I would appreciate detailed instructions on how to install the correct drivers or at least a good generic one that works

Answer (score 0):

The coorect driver `rt2800pci` is already included in default Ubuntu 20.04 installations. Compiling a perhaps older driver from some unknown source is unlikely to help.

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: i will try above steps ...im basically having issues when playing on my shadow after 10 20 mins the connection is super laggy but doesnt seem to disconect but when i close shadow it almost imediatly shows that the wifi is unavailible...usually if i turn the wifi on then back off in the control panel the internet imediatly comes back on for a while ? does this narrow anything down or help figure out my problem ? as i said i am new to this completly i installed ubuntu yesterday and am merley going off what im learning as i go. lol so again any help and tips would be apreciated

Comment: Please try the suggestions above and report back. We will proceed from there.

Comment: ok i have tried the steps above. nothing has worked but i did check the power mangment and it is in fact turned on i tried the above method u mention and typed it in the terminal but it said that directory doesnt exist ...? maybe i typed in the command incorectly but i copied and pasted what was there ..with no luck ? im just trying to find the correct command to turn off power managment i truly believe this is the problem? please help THX

Comment: What does this report? `ls /etc | grep Network`

Comment: it says  "NetworkManager"   with Network being the color red

Comment: How about: `ls /etc/NetworkManager` Is there a file there named conf.d?

Comment: yes there is a conf.d

Comment: What about: `ls /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` ?

Comment: It shows me this "default-wifi-powersave-on.conf"

Comment: Then the file exists and I believe you made a typo in the command. Please retrace your steps and try again.

Comment: i copied and pasted what you originally told me so i dont see how its a typo ?

Comment: "ls /etc | grep Network "    i put exactly this in the terminal and all it said was NetworkManager  network being red i copied and pasted your original reply?

Comment: I copied and pasted the command above: `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` After asking for my password, it completed successfully without complaint. It did *not* say that the file doesn't exist. I confirmed that the file changed with: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and it reports: `[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2` as I expected. What does cat report for you?

Comment: yup you got it bro ..thank you very much